# Unable to create onFormSubmit trigger from Sheets add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, google-workspace

I'm using Google Apps Script to make a sheets add-on where it'll create an installable `onFormSubmit()` trigger to a Form Response sheet by given ID. I've published the add-on as `Unlisted` & everytime the script tries to create the trigger from add-on it gets an error like this,

> This Add-on is attempting to create a trigger on a document that it is not currently being used in.

Here are the codes for creating the trigger,

```
function linkSubSheet(id) {
  var ss_res = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  
  try {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger("onSubmitByAddon").forSpreadsheet(ss_res).onFormSubmit().create();
    Browser.msgBox("The selected sheet has been linked with add-on successfully!");
  } catch(e) {
    Browser.msgBox("Error Log <<"+e+">>");
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: Apps Script prevents an add-on from installing a trigger in a file in which the add-on is not being used.  You can't do it.  See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/triggers#restrictions_2)  https://developers.google.com/gsuite/add-ons/concepts/triggers#restrictions_2

Comment: Damn it, as I feared. I guess I'll have to go to plan B. Thanks for your response!

Comment: What's plan B ?